# Python 2.7 and Pyyaml value max line size

Tags: python-2.7, pyyaml

We have an issue with PyYaml.

When software uses yaml.load() and the value, in key/value tuple, is longer then 120 characters, parser cuts it.

Is there's a way to control max value line length in configuration?